# iOS Loading view upon app launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, launch

for my app i want the app to animate loading progress (loading local CoreData, and syncing with game center) before entering main page.

So i created a LoadingView as my rootview, in the ViewDidLoad(), after the local loading and game center loading finishes, i then push to the main view.

I'm pretty sure it's the wrong approach since i'm getting this warning:
     Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged

Could you let me know what's a good practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you create an initial root view which is very simple with a background and present your progress using a HUD. I use this one:

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

When you have initialised everything, drop the HUD and replace the root view controller with a new one you load using storyboard. I would suggest you add a method to the app delegate you can call which does the switch for you.

You are then off and running with the new root. To change the root you use the following in your app delegate instance.

```
self.newController = <load with storyboard>;
self.window.rootViewController = self.newController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `NSNotificationCenter` to create an observer that hears an event when loading finishes:

You would place the observer in ViewDidLoad, more then likely, in order to remove the `UIView` that you instantiated when your CoreData load began. You will most likely need to construct a spinner view yourself. I usually use QuartzCore to do this and make sure it matches the rest of my app.

Because your core competency is not clear from your post, here is a NSHipster article that discusses the use of this concept: http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/

Answer (score 0):

set your second view controller as root view controller. so you will not get any warning ect.
 `[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] window].rootviewController=secondViewCont;`
only problem is there will not be any page navigation animation. You can observe with delegate or with notification to your loading process.